# Indefinite Cubic integral

Tags: calculus

Evaluate :
$$\int\frac{dx}{ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d}$$
My turn :
let $$I = \int\frac{dx}{(x-l) (x-m) (x-n)}$$
Where $$l , m ,n$$are the roots of the cubic equation$$ax^3 +bx^2 +cx +d$$
Using the partial fraction i got $$I = \frac{1}{(l-m)(l-n)}\ln{(x-l)} + \frac{1}{(m-l)(m-n)}\ln{(x-m)} + \frac{1}{(n-l)(n-m)}) \ln{(x-n)}$$

Then $\frac{-b}{a} = l+m+n$ , $\frac{d}{a}= ln +mn + lm$ , $\frac{c}{a} = lmn$

My question : Is there any procedure to calculate $a , b , c$ In terms of $l, m , n$ ?

Comment: I have edited it , thank you @Chappers

Comment: You are essentially asking to factor a general cubic. This is possible, but very laborious (consult Cardano's method). Further, you do not know if all three roots are real.

Comment: What you did is the right way but your second equation should be $I =\frac 1 a \int\frac{dx}{(x-l) (x-m) (x-n)}$

Answer (score 1):

The Cubic formula is as follows.

$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$$
where
$$x_k=-\frac1{3a}\left(b+\xi^kC+\frac{\Delta_0}{\xi^kC}\right)\qquad k=0,1,2$$
and $$\Delta_0=b^2-3ac,$$
$$\Delta_1=2b^3-9abc+27a^2d,$$
$$C=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\Delta_1\pm \sqrt{\Delta_1^2-4\Delta_0^3}}{2}},$$
$$\xi=\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}.$$
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula) for more info.

You may be interested to know that, given some sequence $A=\{a_k\}_{k=1}^n$ where $i\ne j\iff a_i\ne a_j$, we may find the integral
$$I_A(x)=\int \frac{dx}{f_A(x)}$$
where 
$$f_A(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x-a_k)=(x-a_1)(a-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n).$$
To do so, we do partial fractions and say that
$$\frac{1}{f_A(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{b_k}{x-a_k}.$$
Multiply both sides by $f_A(x)=\prod_{r=1}^{n}(x-a_r)$:
$$1=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k\prod_{k\ne r=1}^n (x-a_r).$$
Then for any $q=1,2,...,n$ we can plug in $x=a_q$. This makes every term on the RHS vanish except for the case $k=q$ so we have
$$1=b_q\prod_{q\ne r=1}^n(a_q-a_r)$$
which is
$$b_q=\prod_{q\ne r=1}^n\frac{1}{a_q-a_r}.$$
That is a rather cumbersome product to deal with, which we luckily can simplify considerably. With the added condition that $f_A(z)=0\Rightarrow f_A'(z)\ne 0$, we note that
$$\ln f_A(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(x-a_k)$$
which means that
$$\frac{f_A'(x)}{f_A(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{x-a_k}$$
i.e.
$$f_A'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f_A(x)}{x-a_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{k\ne r=1}^n(x-a_r).$$
Then if $q=1,2,...,n$ the we can plug in $x=a_q$ to see that everything on the RHS vanishes except for the term $k=q$:
$$f_A'(a_q)=\prod_{q\ne r=1}^n(a_q-a_r)=\frac1{b_q}.$$
So we get, at long last,
$$\frac{1}{f_A(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-a_k)f_A'(a_k)}.$$
We then see that
$$I_A(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{f_A'(a_k)}\int\frac{dx}{x-a_k}=C+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln|x-a_k|}{f_A'(a_k)}.$$
I must admit, this is not especially helpful, except for situations like 
$$f_A(x)=x^n+1=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x-\underbrace{e^{i\pi(2k-1)/n}}_{e_k})$$
so that 
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^n+1}=C+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln|x-e_k|}{ne_k^{n-1}}.$$